# An Almost Homeomorphsim Between Discs is a Homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf R}$
**Notation.** Let $D^n$ denote the closed unit disc in $\R^n$, $B^n$ denote the interior of $D^n$, and $S^{n-1}$ denote the boundary of $D^n$.

> Let $f:D^n\to D^n$ be a surjective continuous map such that
>   1) $f$ maps the interior of $D^n$ homeomorphically onto the interior of $D^n$.
>   2) $f$ maps $S^{n-1}$ into $S^{n-1}$.
>   **Question.** Is it necessary that $f$ is a homeomorphism?

The answer is YES if $n=1$. This is easy to show and this is the motivation behind the question.

The problem seems much trickier for $n>1$.

I have an intuitive argument which suggests that the answer remains YES even for $n=2$.

Suppose $f:D^2\to D^2$ satisfies our hypotheses but is not a homeomorphism. Let $n=2$. Then $f$ is not injective on $S^{n-1}$. We may assume, without loss of generality, that the points $x:=(0, 1)$ and $y:=(0, -1)$ are both mapped to $z:=(1, 0)$ under $f$.

Then the image of the straight line segment $S$ joining $x$ and $y$ is a loop based at $z$. Let $a=(-1, 0)$ and $b=(1, 0)$. By hypothesis, $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are both on $S^{n-1}$. Now the straight line segment $T$ joining $a$ to $b$ cuts $S$ at one point. Since $f$ is injective on $B^n$, the image of $T$ cuts the image of $S$ at only one point. But since $f(S)$ is like a loop, $f(T)$ should cut $f(S)$ at more than one points.

Of course, the above is not a formal argument.

Can somebody help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

consider a "square" $I\times I$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$... consider the quotient map $I\times I \to I\times I /I\times \{1\}$. Now observe that $I\times I$ is homeomorphic to $D^2$ as well as $I\times I /I\times \{1\}$... So take $f$ as the whole composition... this map has all desired properties that you needed, but it is not a homeomorphism. The same you can do for $n\geq 2$.